# mvc3SiteMapProvider: SiteMap Showed properly but Breadcrums not

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, localization, mvcsitemapprovider

Hi I have a site with areas and this

[url localization strategy.](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/01/26/Translating-routes-(ASPNET-MVC-and-Webforms).aspx)

and i have a problem using the mvc3sitemapprovider (Also by marteen...). The nodes are explicitly defined, the sitemap is perfectly shown when i put:

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu(false, true, true)
```

but the Bredcrums path does not appear when sometimes:

```
 @Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()
```

In the pages where the sitemappath is not display, the view and routeData are correct (the page is properly displayed) and the data of the node are also correct. Here a sample:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="$resources:URL, LinkSolPerso" clickable="false" >

  <mvcSiteMapNode  title="$resources:URL, LinkInteg" area="soluciones_personalizadas"  controller="integracion"  action="Index" />


    <mvcSiteMapNode  title="$resources:URL, LinkServOfre" area="soluciones_personalizadas" controller="proyectos"  action="servicios-ofrecidos" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode  title="$resources:URL, LinkTrabRea" area="soluciones_personalizadas" controller="proyectos"  action="trabajos-realizados" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode  title="$resources:URL, LinkObtPres" area="soluciones_personalizadas" controller="proyectos"  action="obtener-presupuesto" />

  <mvcSiteMapNode  title="$resources:URL, LinkSolPerso" area="soluciones_personalizadas" controller="formacion"  action="Index" />

  <mvcSiteMapNode  title="$resources:URL, LinkPromPat" area="soluciones_personalizadas" controller="promociones_patrocinios"  action="Index" />

</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

The issue is that i do not know what can be happening (the nodes are correct as they are displayed in the sitmap...) nor the best way to debug...

Thanks¡¡

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what was wrong. But for saving your time I should tell that I have fixed it dowloading the source code from the project (before I was using the nuget package) and referencing it. Doing this way everything runs perfect.